# Can I install both .net 2.0 framework and .net 4.0 framework in a PC?

Tags: .net-framework, .net-2.0, .net-4.0

Can I install both .net 2.0 framework and .net 4.0 framework in one PC ?

Now Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express has been installed in my PC, but when I run older asp.net project , the system require to install  .net 2.0 framework.  I'm afraid that new .net 4.0 project maybe meet trouble after I install old .net 2.0 framework  in my PC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There won't be any problems. They can both be installed on the same PC, without one messing up the other. They install to different folders.